# Conditional return type

Tags: typescript

I have created [`mini-jsx`](https://gitlab.com/appsemble/mini-jsx/blob/1.0.2/h.ts#L429-474). This is a tiny library for creating DOM elements using JSX syntax. It is written in TypeScript.

Now I would like to extend it to support function components. I have fiddled a lot, but couldn’t find a way to define proper type annotations. This is what I ended up with:

```
const h = <
  T extends (keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap) | ((props?: P, children?: Child[]) => Node),
  P extends object
>(
  tag: T,
  props?: T extends (keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap) ? Props<T> : P,
  ...children: Children[]
): T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap ? HTMLElementTagNameMap[T] : ReturnType<T> => {
  const childArray: Child[] = [];
  const flattenChildren = (child: Children): void => {
    if (Array.isArray(child)) {
      child.forEach(flattenChildren);
    } else if (child != null && child !== true && child !== false) {
      childArray.push(child);
    }
  };
  flattenChildren(children);
  if (typeof tag !== "string") {
    return tag(props as P, childArray) as ReturnType<T>;
  }
  let ref: Ref<T> | undefined;
  const node = document.createElement(tag);
  if (props) {
    Object.entries(props).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (key === "ref") {
        ref = value as Ref<T>;
      } else if (key in node) {
        type Key = keyof typeof node;
        if (node[key as Key] instanceof Object && value instanceof Object) {
          Object.assign(node[key as Key], value);
        } else {
          node[key as Key] = value as typeof node[Key];
        }
      } else {
        node.setAttribute(key, value as string);
      }
    });
  }
  node.append(...(childArray as Node[]));
  if (ref) {
    ref(node);
  }
  return node;
};
```

If I would write just the type definitions, the function would have 2 call signatures:

- one would accept an HTML tag name and partial DOM node, and return the DOM node that is mapped to the given tag name;
- the other would accept a function that accepts props and children and returns a DOM node, and just calls that function with the given props and flattened children.

```
type Child = number | string | Node;

interface ChildrenArray extends Array<Children> {}
type Children = boolean | null | undefined | Child | ChildrenArray;

interface Attributes<T> {
  // truncated
}

type Props<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap> = Attributes<T> &
  {
    [K in keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap[T]]?: HTMLElementTagNameMap[T][K] extends Function
      ? HTMLElementTagNameMap[T][K]
      : Partial<HTMLElementTagNameMap[T][K]>;
  };

export function h<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(
  tag: T,
  props?: Partial<HTMLElementTagNameMap[T]>,
  ...children: Children[]
): HTMLElementTagNameMap[T];

export function h<T extends (props?: object, children?: Child[]) => Node>(
  tag: T,
  props?: Parameters<T>[0],
  ...children: Children[]
): ReturnType<T>;
```

Currently I’m getting these errors:

```
h.ts:452:82 - error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type '"object" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "track" | "progress" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "basefont" | "bdi" | ... 100 more ... | ((props?: P, children?: Child[]) => Node)' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
    Type '"object"' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.

452 ): T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap ? HTMLElementTagNameMap[T] : ReturnType<T> => {
                                                                                     ~

h.ts:463:5 - error TS2322: Type 'ReturnType<T>' is not assignable to type 'T extends "object" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "track" | "progress" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "basefont" | "bdi" | ... 99 more ... | "wbr" ? HTMLElementTagNameMap[T] : ReturnType<...>'.

463     return tag(props as P, childArray) as ReturnType<T>;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

h.ts:463:12 - error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '"object" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "track" | "progress" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "basefont" | "bdi" | ... 100 more ... | ((props?: P, children?: Child[]) => Node)' has no compatible call signatures.

463     return tag(props as P, childArray) as ReturnType<T>;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

h.ts:463:54 - error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.

463     return tag(props as P, childArray) as ReturnType<T>;
                                                         ~

h.ts:465:16 - error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '"object" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "track" | "progress" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "basefont" | "bdi" | ... 99 more ... | "wbr"'.
  Type '"object" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "track" | "progress" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "basefont" | "bdi" | ... 100 more ... | ((props?: P, children?: Child[]) => Node)' is not assignable to type '"object" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "track" | "progress" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "basefont" | "bdi" | ... 99 more ... | "wbr"'.
    Type '(props?: P, children?: Child[]) => Node' is not assignable to type '"object" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "track" | "progress" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "basefont" | "bdi" | ... 99 more ... | "wbr"'.
      Type '(props?: P, children?: Child[]) => Node' is not assignable to type '"wbr"'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type '"wbr"'.
          Type '"object" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "track" | "progress" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "basefont" | "bdi" | ... 100 more ... | ((props?: P, children?: Child[]) => Node)' is not assignable to type '"wbr"'.
            Type '"object"' is not assignable to type '"wbr"'.

465   let ref: Ref<T> | undefined;
                   ~

h.ts:466:39 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type '"object" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "track" | "progress" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "basefont" | "bdi" | ... 100 more ... | ((props?: P, children?: Child[]) => Node)' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type '(props?: P, children?: Child[]) => Node' is not assignable to type 'string'.

466   const node = document.createElement(tag);
                                          ~~~

h.ts:470:28 - error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '"object" | "link" | "small" | "sub" | "sup" | "track" | "progress" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "basefont" | "bdi" | ... 99 more ... | "wbr"'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type '"wbr"'.

470         ref = value as Ref<T>;
```

I have created the following working tests. I have also been using these to verify TypeScript is able to identify the exact types.

```
test("HTML without JSX or props", () => {
  const li = h("li");
  expect(li).toBeInstanceOf(HTMLLIElement);
});

test("Function without JSX with props", () => {
  function Div({ bar }: { bar: string }): HTMLDivElement {
    return <div className={bar} /> as HTMLDivElement;
  }
  const div = h(Div, { bar: "test" });
  expect(div).toBeInstanceOf(HTMLDivElement);
  expect(div.className).toBe("test");
});

test("Function without JSX or props", () => {
  function Div(): HTMLDivElement {
    return <div /> as HTMLDivElement;
  }
  const div = h(Div);
  expect(div).toBeInstanceOf(HTMLDivElement);
});
```

How do I fix these types? Or am I better off converting the code to JavaScript instead and separate typings into a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: Why not use overloads for `h` if you already know what they should be.You would need to convert to a function declaration, but nothing much is gained here by the arrow synatx.

Comment: I just tried this:

`function h<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(
  tag: T,
  props: Props<T>,
  ...children: Children[]
): HTMLElementTagNameMap[T];
function h<T extends (props?: P, children?: Child[]) => Node>(
  tag: T,
  props: Parameters<T>[0],
  ...children: Children[]
): ReturnType<T> {...}`

but now tag is always considered to be a function inside the function body.